# Can't seem to inject CSS onto YouTube?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to inject JS and CSS into YouTube pages. I am able to inject JS, but see no effect when injecting CSS. Am I doing something incorrect or is YouTube limiting me in some manner?

Here's the relevant portion of my manifest.json:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.youtube.com/watch?v*"],
      "css": ["ChromeExtension/css/inject.css"],
      "js": ["ChromeExtension/js/thirdParty/underscore.js", "ChromeExtension/js/thirdParty/jquery.js", "ChromeExtension/js/inject.js"]
    }
  ]
```

I see all of the js injected properly, but no effect with the css. My CSS does not appear to have been injected at all:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Curious.. injecting this code works, but I have also attempted applying '!important' to all the css properties. These two methods had **different** effects which contrasts others solutions provided on StackOverflow.

I had more success with this, but remain curious as to why the more concise definition fails:

```
var style = document.createElement('link');
style.rel = 'stylesheet';
style.type = 'text/css';
style.href = chrome.extension.getURL('ChromeExtension/css/inject.css');
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

Comment: `!important` was going to be my de facto suggestion. Strange indeed...

Comment: Yeah agreed. My testing CSS was just body { background-color: #000 !important; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `!important`, just make sure that you have a higher specificity in your css to override what is already there. If you look at the `body`'s style, you should see something like this: [image]

This shows that the css is being applied, just being overridden. Changing your css to something like

```
body.ltr{
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Will work just fine.

Edit:
On top of that, the problem might actually be with the `?` in the match pattern. For me `http:///www.youtube.com/watch*` works while `http:///www.youtube.com/watch?*` does not. As for why this affects the injection of the `css`, but not the `js` I have no clue.